# Select Every Nth Row and Move to Columns

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have been searching for a bit and have come across a few possible answers, but being so not well versed in Excel Macros, I am unsure how to tweak any possible solution to my direct need.

As such, I currently have an Excel data-set with 10,000 records per the following example:

```
Name
Street
City, State Zip
Name
Street
City, State Zip
etc
```

My desire is to be able to move all the rows with `street` into their own column and move `city, state zip` into its own column.

So the spreadsheet looks like:

```
Name     Street    City, State    Zip
Name     Street    City, State    Zip
Name     Street    City, State    Zip
```

Comment: Do all the records have exactly three lines?  If the City is missing is the comma still there?  No comma between State and Zip?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple `Sub` to reshape your data, with som comments to explain each step.

It has no data integrity checking or error handling, you should add this to make a robust solution

```
Sub ReshapeData()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Src As Variant, Dst As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    ' Get Data From Sheet
    ' Assumes data starts at A1 on active sheet and has no gaps
    Set rng = Range([A1], [A1].End(xlDown))
    ' Copy data to a variant array
    Src = rng
    ' Set size of another array to match result
    ReDim Dst(1 To UBound(Src) / 3, 1 To 3)
    '  Loop through source array, copy data to desination array
    For i = 0 To UBound(Dst) - 1
        Dst(i + 1, 1) = Src(i * 3 + 1, 1)
        Dst(i + 1, 2) = Src(i * 3 + 2, 1)
        Dst(i + 1, 3) = Src(i * 3 + 3, 1)
    Next
    ' Delete original data
    rng.ClearContents
    ' Put new data on sheet
    rng.Resize(UBound(Dst), 3) = Dst
End Sub
```

Comment: Yep this worked perfectly. Unfortunately as time constraints forced me to find a far less elegant (and tedious) way to manage the project at the time, this is definitely good to know for the future.